# Property [images] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, collections, properties, instance, message

PLease I need help figuring out this problem, I have two model Event and EventImages with One-To-Many relationsip, each event can have multiple images, so I want to be able to loop through Events using the images method from the Event Model and display each event with one image from multiple images of that event on the index page, and make each image a link to the show page where there is Carousel that will display all the images belonging to that event. I keep getting this error

**Property [images] does not exist on this collection instance.**

**This is the Event Model**

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'date', 'time', 'venue', 'body'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventImage');
    }
}
```

**Event migration**

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('time');
        $table->string('venue');
        $table->mediumText('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**This is EventImage Model**

```
class EventImage extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['images', 'caption','event_id'];

    public function event()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
    }
    
}
```

**EventImage migration**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('event_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();   
        $table->string('images');
        $table->string('caption');
        $table->integer('event_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('event_id')->references('id')->on('events')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**This is the EventController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Event;
use App\EventImage;

    class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
    
       $events = Event::all();
       $imageEvents = $events->images->take(1);
      
       return view('events.index', compact('events', $events, 'imageEvents', 
   $imageEvents));
      
    }
```

**This is the view**

```
 <div class="container">

 <div class="tab_">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#section1">Recent Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2">All Events</a></li>
  
  </ul>
  <section id="section1">
    <div class="col s12 m7 s7">
  @foreach ($events as $k =>  $event)
   @if ($k % 2 == 0)
      <div class="card horizontal">
              <div class="card-image">
                  {{-- <img src="{{asset('images/amber-heard-7031- 
        2560x1600_1598312173.jpg')}}" class="fadeIn"> --}}
                  @foreach ($imageEvents as $imageEvent)
                     <a href=""><img class="img-fluid d-block card-img" style 
  ="width:100%" src="{{asset('storage/images')}}/{{$imageEvent->images}}" 
  alt=""> 
 </a>  
                  @endforeach
                
              </div>
              <div class="card-stacked">
                <div class="card-content">
                  <span class="card-title">{{$event->title}}</span>
                  <p>{{$event->body}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          
             
          </div>


          <div class="col s12 m7">
 @else
            <div class="card horizontal" id="fadedfx">

              <div class="card-stacked">
                <div class="card-content">
                  <span class="card-title">{{$event->title}}</span>
                  <p>{{$event->body}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                  <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-image">
                   <a href=""><img class="img-fluid d-block card-img" style 
     ="width:100%" src="{{asset('storage/images')}}/{{$imageEvent->images}}" 
      alt=""></a>
              </div>
            </div>
 @endif
 @endforeach
          </div>
```

**This is the Route**

```
     **Route::resource('events', 'EventController', [
     'names'=> [
       'index'     => 'eventdex',
       'create'    => 'createvent',
       'store'     => 'storevent',
       'show'      => 'showevent',
       'edit'      => 'editevent',
       'update'    => 'updateevent',
       'destroy'   => 'destroyevent'
    ]
 ]);**
```

But when I make this changes to the EventController and save it

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

   $events = Event::all();
   
   $event = Event::find(49);
   $imageEvents = $event->images->take(1);
  
   return view('events.index', compact('events', $events, 'imageEvents', 
  $imageEvents));
  
}
```

it works fine except is not dynamic, I had to put in the event id the find method, and only one image show for all the events.

Comment: `$events` is a `Collection`, you can't access `->images` unless you're looping, or only loading a single Event via `Event::first()`.

Comment: it will be like this ..`Event::with('images')->get();`

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor No, using `with('images')` will not make a difference here. `get()` still returns a `Collection`; same issue applies.

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor No! It will not... `$events` is still a `Collection` there... `get()` returns a `Collection`. Stop guessing please and try your code out locally.

Comment: why he make eloquent relationship  ? also he looking for image ? i don't know  what you guessing ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor You're missing the point. In the code, they have `$events = Event::all()`, then trying to call `$events->images`. This doesn't work, regardless of the code you posted. It needs to be either `$event = Event::first()`, then `$event->images`, or `foreach($events as $event){ $event->images }`. This has nothing to do with how the images relationship is defined or included. If they want to do `$event->images->first()`, they can do that, but they need to solve the core issue first.

Comment: why he use `take(1)`.. like this... would you explain this `$events->images->take(1);`  ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor Ok, I appreciate you trying to help, but you don't seem to understand the problem here. `$events->images` **will never work with the code posted**; that's the main problem.

Comment: Thank you @Abdullah All Noor for commenting, I am new to Laravel so there might be a lot of wrong coding, with this $events->images->take(1);  I tried to grab one image from the collection of imagesof the event instead of looping through the images since i only need to display one image in the index page for every event. Thank You

Comment: Thank You @Tim Lewis for the comment